# Why does the Content-Security-Policy settings in web.config have no effect?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-security-policy

In a small ASP.NET MVC test application, I added the appropriate `httpProtocol` code to the `web.config` file, as described in [this article](https://blog.elmah.io/content-security-policy-in-asp-net-mvc/):

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
      <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
              <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'" />
          </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

However, on a test page in the application, the Vue.js code still works, which, since it is being loaded from a CDN, the content security policy should be blocking it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home Page2 - Meine ASP.NET-Anwendung</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.4/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mainMenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Start Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Home/Info">Info</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <hr/>



<div id="app">
    this is a test: <b>{{message}}</b>
</div>


<script>

    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'Vue.js ready'
        }
    });
</script>
        <hr/>
        <footer>
            <p>The footer</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

**What do I have to do to get the Content Security Policy to actually take effect in my site?**

## ADDENDUM

I can see in my dev tools, that the Content-Security-Policy is not being sent in the response headers:

[image]

Comment: You may first need something like<remove name="Content-Security-Policy"/> then add your custom header, This is how I  modify mimetype few years ago.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49344540/713789

Comment: @Adrian, I added `<remove name="Content-Security-Policy"/>` one line above `<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'" />`, but it had no effect.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the header is being set correctly using the dev tools or something like postman?

Comment: check the resulting request to see whether the header is actually being sent or not.

Comment: @EdwardTanguay try it by modifying the applicationHost.config

Comment: I don't see Content-Security-Policy in headers shown in dev tools, I posted a screenshot above.

Comment: @Adrian if we wanted to set this for all sites, I would set it in the Default Site settings in IIS (Http-Response-Headers), which we have determined works. But we would like to be able to set this individually for each site, which is why we want to it it working in the `web.config` file.

Comment: @EdwardTanguay No, I mean that you can set per site in ApplicationHost. It has more priority than application web.config. check my earlier link. in that link person does that for his site specifically.

Comment: @EdwardTanguay I wanted to check-in to see if you were able to get your content policy working in your Web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the configuration block below in your question, makes me assume you have added the `<httpProtocol><customHeaders> ...` section to the `web.config`file in the `Views` folder instead of the `web.config` file in the root of your website.

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
        <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```